# Why is the LayoutLM installation fails to install?

Tags: python, installation, google-colaboratory, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I want to install `LayoutLM` in `Google Colaboratory`

First, I have cloned the `LayoutLM` from this *GitHub* repository

https://github.com/microsoft/unilm.git

After that, I will install the `LayoutLM` by running its `setup.py` file by running this code block:

```
%%bash
cd /content/drive/MyDrive/LayoutLMMM/SROIE2019-20210928T080219Z-001/SROIE2019
# git clone https://github.com/microsoft/unilm.git
cd unilm/layoutlm/deprecated
pip install .
```

However, when i tried to run the script, an error occurs

```
Successfully built layoutlm sacremoses
Failed to build tokenizers
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for tokenizers (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tokenizers
ERROR: Could not build wheels for tokenizers, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

As I locate what library is causing the error, I found out that the `tokenizers` library in the `transformers` of `HuggingFace` is returning this error.

I have tried modifying the `setup` file by omitting the `transformers` library and modified the setup script of transformers to install the latest version of `tokenizer` to check if it can fix the error. Yes, this method works however, the results are not accurate.

How can I install the LayoutLM without the `building wheel for tokenizers did not run successfully` error?

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies with the `tokenizer` version `0.7` being incompatible with the `python 3.10`. In my case, I have tried to change the python version to `3.7.0` and I was able to install it without any issues. To do this in Google Colab, I have run these series of code blocks:

This code block will install `python 3.7`

```
!sudo apt-get install python3.7
!sudo apt-get update -y
```

This code block will switch the python version into version 3.7

```
!sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 1
!sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

This code block will install the pip

```
!sudo apt install python3-pip
```

With this, the layoutlm can be installed without the error